# Is $1/x^n$ uniformly convergent on $(1,2)$

Tags: calculus, analysis, uniform-convergence

I just got the definition of pointwise and uniform convergence for sequences of functions. I have not yet seen any theorems related to these notions, only the definitions. I have been playing around with examples to make sure I really understand them.

The first example I came up with was the sequence $f_n = x^{-n}$. First I chose these functions to be defined on [1,2] and it was easy enough to show that $f_n \to f(x) = 0$, pointwise. It was also pretty easy to see that on [1,2] the sequence would necessarily fail uniform convergence since no function in my sequence will ever budge at $x = 1$. But what if I chose the domain as (1,2)? I have been unable to prove that it is or is not uniformly convergent to $f(x) = 0$ on this domain. I conjecture that it *will not* be uniformly convergent since if we get close enough to $x = 1$, there should always be some $x$ that raised to a finite exponent will fail to be less than $\epsilon$, but I am having trouble constructing an argument.

To be honest I only tried for about 10 minutes, but I really should be working on other things right now. Thanks for any help, happy to provide more information or examples of what I have tried if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $f_n(\sqrt[n]{2}) = {1 \over 2}$. Hence $\sup_{x \in (1,2)} |f_n (x) - 0| \ge {1 \over 2}$.

Comment: Clever, I was having trouble constructing an argument since there was multiple variable quantities... I didn't think to use $n$ in my choice of $x$. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, wait. Now I have a serious dilemma. I moved on in my notes since we cleared this up and the next proof assigned of me is to show that if a sequence of bounded functions converges, then it must converge uniformly. But as far as I am concerned the example we just constructed is a counter example to this since all of the functions in this sequence are bounded, but we just showed it does not converge uniformly?

Comment: What do you mean by 'a sequence of bounded functions converges'?

Comment: We have defined $B(X)$ to be the set of all bounded functions $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$, and bounded is just saying the range is bounded. We have proven that $(B(X),d)$ is a metric space with the metric $d(f,g) = \mathrm{sup}\{|f(x)-g(x)| : x \in X \}$

Comment: So the problem says 'prove that if a sequence in $B(X)$ converges, then it converges uniformly. I think the confusion might be that I am not using the metric we have equipped $B(X)$ with, but I dont think it would make sense to in the definition of convergence since all these functions map into $\mathbb{R}$ by definition, so it makes sense to use the Euclidean.

Comment: Not sure if I am mis understanding the problem or if its just blatantly wrong?

Comment: After more scrutinous investigation I think the problem is the fact that I was not using the metric on $B(X)$ in my hypothesis that the sequence was convergent.

Comment: actually, yeah, duh. With what we just showed this sequence would not be convergent in $B(X)$.

Comment: Yes to your last comment.